# EnumDisplayMonitors and EnumDisplaySettings disagree

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

In my program I call [EnumDisplayMonitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx) with my own user [MonitorEnumProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145061(v=vs.85).aspx).  My callback receives a `RECT` (`lprcMonitor`) reporting the monitor's display size.  Inside my callback I call [EnumDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx) to get some other information.  `lprcMonitor` reports that the display is 2560x1440, while `EnumDisplaySettings` returns a `DEVMODE` with a 3840x2160 resolution.

The call to `EnumDisplayMonitors` looks like this:

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
EnumDisplayMonitors(hDC, NULL,
                   MonitorEnumProc,
                   (LPARAM)&myModeList);
```

I am not providing a clipping rectangle, hence the `NULL` argument, so EnumDisplayMonitors should report the full monitor and not a select region of it.  I am also providing the `DC` of the desktop, which makes the function report the "display monitor rectangle:"

> If hdcMonitor is non-NULL, this rectangle is the intersection of the
>   clipping area of the device context identified by hdcMonitor and the
>   display monitor rectangle. The rectangle coordinates are
>   device-context coordinates.

The actual resolution is 3840x2160, which is what is reported when I call `EnumDisplaySettings`:

```
if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &info)) {
    DEVMODE mode;

    mode.dmSize = sizeof mode;

    if (!EnumDisplaySettings(info.szDevice,
                             ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &mode)) {

...
```

What would cause this discrepency?  There is only one monitor and it is never set to a resolution of 2560x1440 throughout the runtime of my program.  Currently my program relies on lprcMonitor to determine the size of a buffer to create, should it rely on `EnumDisplaySettings`'s answer instead?

EDIT:  The answer likely involves DPI.  The problem doesn't show up when DPI is set to 100%.

Comment: Did you declare your application as DPI-aware in the manifest?

Comment: @doynax Nope - will that cause EnumDisplayMonitors to report the real resolution?

Comment: Please, please, please use parenthesis for the argument of `sizeof()`

Comment: @NmdMystery: Very likely. Since Vista Windows DPI scaling is opt-in due to poor compatibility from a mass of applications expecting the default setting and hard-coding pixel sizes. The scheme used is to fake a lower resolution image for the application and up-scale the results. This would involve lying about the final on-screen sizes of display elements.

Comment: @Michaël Roy: Did you have any particular reason in mind? I can't see any obvious dangers in leaving out parenthesis from the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: That notation is not supported by most compilers, for starters.

Comment: @Michaël Roy: Can you give an example? I have never encountered that issue. The parenthesis are required to disambiguate types but the C syntax permits arbitrary expressions (the variable `mode` here) without them.

Comment: gcc, cl. code is: `int main() { return sizeof int; }`

Comment: @Michaël Roy: Well, yes, but `int` is a type and not an expression. I believe the code above should be perfectly portable.

Comment: Then it is dangerous, because expressions are ambiguous by nature. Why does `int main() { char c; return sizeof c + 1L; } return 2 ?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy This code isn't originally mine and this is the syntax used throughout.

Comment: @Michaël Roy: *Shrug*. That's just the precedence of unary operators in C, much like `!0 + 1`. To what degree you add redundant parentheses to clarify this would depend on how comfortable you and your expected audience are with the rules. Again, though, the code in question lacks any such ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

*EnumDisplaySettings* return true resolution of display.

*EnumDisplayMonitors* and similar functions are a subject to scalling - which means that if your application is not declared as "dpi aware", OS will lie to it about screen size in most functions when scalling is not 100%.

Scalling will make sure, that your "not dpi aware" app windows are not too small on high dpi screens (with side effect of blurriness).

My favorite article about this topic is on MSDN:[Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dn469266).

Comment: Are these APIs relevant in Windows 10 or they are outdated and replaced by something else?

Comment: EnumDisplayMonitors, EnumDisplaySettings work fine on all recent Windows 10 versions. I'm not aware of any newer C api with the same purpose.